# Disable Inputs After Form Submission with jQuery Form Plugin

Tags: jquery

Gist of my HTML (I have multiple forms on the same page)

```
<tr>
    <form method="post" class="save-form" id="93">
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> <input type="submit" value="save" name="save" class="save hidden" />
        </td>
        <td class="center gray">
            <input type="text" value="234" name="views" />
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

I'm using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#html).

```
$('.save-form').each(function() {
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            //
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //
        }
    });
});


$('.save-form').submit(function() { 
    $(this).parent().find('a.edit').show();
    $(this).parent().find('input.save').hide();
 // $(this).parent().find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

All of this works fine.

But I want to move everything from `$('.save-form').submit(function() {` into `success:`. I couldn't figure it out with the HTML I have..

I also want to disable the `save` input after the form has been submitted. If I try to with `$('.save-form').submit(function() {`, it disables the input, BUT won't submit the input data - I think because the input is being disabled before being processed. If it is disabled from within `success:` it should work, but I can't figure that out either.

How can I process the form and then disable the inputs?

Comment: Show us your disable statement

Comment: @Adil `$(this).parent().find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: @bjauy has answered I hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

I would say, you should try it this way:

```
$('.save-form').each(function() {
    var form = this;
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            $(form).parent().find('input.save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(form).parent().find('a.edit').show();
            $(form).parent().find('input.save').hide();
        }
    });
});
```